# Use Flow ESLint with "flowtype/no-weak-types" in Vue Component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, eslint, flowtype

When writing a component in VueJS with Flow ESLint enabled, I get the error on a components data() method:

> ESLint: Missing return type annotation. (flowtype/no-weak-types)

Now, I don't want to allow weak types.
If I write a custom type for each components data() method, that would be too much code duplication.

```js
export default {
  data(): Object {
    return {
      some: "data",
      here: "and there"
    };
  },
  // ...
};
```

Question: Is there a better way to handle this? E.g. can I let Flow ignore  this data() method inside components in a nice way?

Thanks!

Comment: You can wrap it with `/* eslint-disable */` and `/* eslint-enable */`. I post as a comment because it's a workaround, maybe someone as a better answer. If not i'll post it as answer.

Comment: This works, but it is not really a nice way.
I found out, that I can add some "excludeMatch" to "flowtype/require-return-type" in the eslint rules. But that did not work or short-hand methods :/
So I still looking for a better solution.

Comment: Is `*` considered weak? Seems like a good case for existential types.

Comment: @LyleUnderwood Will use that. Thanks!